# How to save data on Windows Store App Close?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-runtime

i have the following problem. When the user closes the Windows store app, i want a text file with data to be saved.

What method should i write so that when closing the app a file gets saved ?

Comment: The user will not close your app. Look for the Suspending events.

Comment: That means if you go in the left corner, right-click->close, the app isn't actually closed ? I thought suspending is when you press the windows-button.

Comment: You are waiting too long to save the data.  Store apps get killed unceremoniously when Windows requires resources.  You need to save when you get suspended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx) describes the application lifecycle of a Windows Store App.

If you look at the very first figure, you can see that there are only 3 events related to application lifecycle:

1. **Activated** - Raised when program first starts
2. **Suspended** - Raised when program is suspended (i.e. the user returns to the Start Screen or another app)
3. **Resuming** - Raised when the program is awakened from its suspended state.

The fourth transition - the one to the "Not Running" state - has no such notification event.  The reason is: you don't really know when the app will fully close.  Nor should you - Microsoft wants you to perform all of your state-saving logic in the transition from "Running" to "Suspended."  In this way, they can free up resources when they deem necessary.

Even if the user forces the program to terminate (by right-clicking it and selecting "Close" from the task menu), you will enter the "Suspended" state for exactly 10 seconds before the program is terminated.  So you can rest easy that your state-saving logic will always be executed.

Answer (score 0):

> you don't really know when the app will fully close. Nor should you...

I don't agree with this - Microsoft are copying this from Apple, and I don't know why, I never liked Apple's implementation either.

If your user makes changes to your App, then closes it using the keyboard or gesture, then restarts it say after 6 seconds, all changes are lost.

I don't see any way as a developer to get around this. Whoever decided that closed events (and exit buttons for that matter) are evil is an idiot.

Comment: I did find a way to get around this - you can save your app state when you get a CoreWindow::Activated (CoreWindowActivationState::Deactivate) event.

Comment: Methinks you didn't actually read my entire answer.  Your hypothetical situation was already accounted for.  In short, save your state when the program is suspended.  Your program is always guaranteed to be suspended for 10 seconds before it exits fully.