# Application closed event in windows store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I want to get event when windows store app is closing or page is closing same way as we get "Closing" event in Desktop application.

Can anybody suggest me?

Comment: The nearest thing that you are looking for is called *Suspended state*. Which raised when user returns to the start screen or another app.

Comment: you want event when another application is closed or closing? correct

Comment: @AnkurTripathi I want to save data when my application (window store app) close. So event must be fire on closing.

Comment: its c# wpf windows application ?

Comment: @AnkurTripathi No, it's not WPF. It's Windows Store Application, c# based.

Comment: @S.Akbari Does OnSuspend event in App.cs call everytime when user close the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx

refer:- [How to save data on Windows Store App Close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075970/how-to-save-data-on-windows-store-app-close)

If you look at the very first figure, you can see that there are only 3 events related to application lifecycle:

**Activated** - Raised when program first starts

**Suspended** - Raised when program is suspended (i.e. the user returns to the Start Screen or another app)

**Resuming** - Raised when the program is awakened from its suspended state.

The fourth transition - the one to the "Not Running" state - has no such notification event. The reason is: you don't really know when the app will fully close. Nor should you - Microsoft wants you to perform all of your state-saving logic in the transition from "Running" to "Suspended." In this way, they can free up resources when they deem necessary.

Even if the user forces the program to terminate (by right-clicking it and selecting "Close" from the task menu), you will enter the "Suspended" state for exactly 10 seconds before the program is terminated. So you can rest easy that your state-saving logic will always be executed.

Comment: Which event I need to handle and where? I have tried to handle private async void OnSuspending(); in App.cs but it doesn't call when I close the application by dragging screen to down of the screen.

Comment: The whole idea behind this is when my app is running in VS2013, it is working fine. But when I deploy it and try ALT + TAB frequently, it redirect to LogIn page.

Comment: when you press ALT+TAB and your application enter to the de-active mode you want to redirect  on LogIn page ?

Comment: No, Ex. If I am redirecting from Product page to Sales page and I frequently press ALT+TAB, application redirect to LogIn page. It should be redirect to Sales page rather. It is because of Frame get null.

Comment: you question is different "Application closed event in windows store app" and you are asking about ALT+TAB  edit or ask the different question

Comment: I got the answer from your reply. I was explaining the actual issue for which  I have asking this question. Thank you.